# Copying and Pasting images from one ps tab to another get resized

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Im experiencing the following problem:

When I copy and image from one photoshop tab to another it gets resized automatically. My image is 25*25 and I want to place it in a A3 paper, so it does fit in its original size.

Im using photoshop CC 2015. And I have already unchecked "resize image during place" but still no luck.

Comment: Resolution of one document is probably different from that of the other.

Comment: I dont understand, Im talking about an empty canvas, what does resolution have to do with it?

Comment: Let's say your photo is 300ppi and your blank A3 is 72ppi. Then when you paste it over it's going to look enormous. Likewise if your photo is 72ppi and you're putting it on a 300ppi blank document then its going to look tiny. This is how resolution works.

Comment: `Resize image during place` option only downsizes the placed image if it's bigger than the document you place it in.

Comment: Alright, I understand, I just dont get why my 25cm image wont stay like that. Im just changing from an A4 to an A3, image should stay 25cm... I mean, thats what it measures, and thats what I made it measure so that when it gets printed I can pick up a ruler and measure 25cm.

Comment: I suggest you look up some articles about how resolution works. Here's how you can check the resolution in photoshop: If you open `Image > Image size...` you can see the current resolution of your document. Alternatively you can open `Window > Info` and at the top right of the panel, there's that little menu icon where you can go to `> Panel options...`. In there you can check `Document dimensions`: [Now if you switch between documents, you can see the resolution of your current document in parenthesis.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pave19274it765g/PS-info-panel-res.png?raw=1).